# How to retrieve the column value based on formula

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

Using a view in SQL Server 2000

`Table1`:

```
id  z1      z2      z3      z4   type
--------------------------------------
01A 300     400     300     400  01
2B  300     400     300     400  02
3C  500     300     400     300  01
04A 500     400     500     400  01
05B 400     300     400     300  02
06  150     200     200     150  03
....
```

`Table2`:

```
type  Formula1           Formula2
------------------------------------    
01    ((Z1+Z2)/1000)*2   null
02    null               ((Z3+Z4)/1000)*2
03    ((Z1+Z2)/1000)*2   ((Z3+Z4)/1000)*2
```

I want to select the `table1` rows based on `table2` formula:

- in table2 type - 01 (z1 and z2 found) then i want to consider table1 z1 z2 columns
- in table2 type - 02 (z3 and z4 found) then i want to consider table1 z3 z4 columns
- in table2 type - 03 (z1, z2, z3 and z4 found) then i want to consider table1 z1, z2, z3 z4 columns

Expected output

`Table1`:

```
id   z1     z2     z3     z4    type
-------------------------------------    
01A  300    400    null   null  01
2B   null   null   300    400   02
3C   500    300    null   null  01
04A  500    400    null   null  01
05B  null   null   400    300   02
06   150    200    200    150   03
```

Currently I'm using a view, I don't want to change to stored procedure because most of the report are using this view.

How to do it in sql..?

Comment: @Mitch, i am trying to find the way, if any way i got, i will post that also...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you need? Query works in SQL Sever 2005, donno about 2000, please check:

```
select a.ID,
  (CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%Z1%', ISNULL(b.Formula1,'')+ISNULL(b.Formula2,''))<>0 THEN a.Z1 ELSE NULL END) Z1,
  (CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%Z2%', ISNULL(b.Formula1,'')+ISNULL(b.Formula2,''))<>0 THEN a.Z2 ELSE NULL END) Z2,
  (CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%Z3%', ISNULL(b.Formula1,'')+ISNULL(b.Formula2,''))<>0 THEN a.Z3 ELSE NULL END) Z3,
  (CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%Z4%', ISNULL(b.Formula1,'')+ISNULL(b.Formula2,''))<>0 THEN a.Z4 ELSE NULL END) Z4, 
  b.* 
From TABLE1 a inner join TABLE2 b on a.type=b.type
```